# I booked a self service appointment for my UK Visa but I didn't upload all my documents by accident and I can't go back and add more

Tags: visas, uk

I booked a self service appointment for my UK Visa but I didn't upload all my documents by accident and I can't go back and add more. One of the most important documents is missing and if it isn't there my visa will definitely get refused. What can I do?

Comment: Can you completely cancel it and start over?

Comment: From what country are you applying? What site did you upload documents to?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify questions in comments. Put on hold for now.